# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (30, 30, 3) but got array with shape (30, 30, 4)

Tags: classification, image

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import os
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout

data = []
labels = []
classes = 43
cur_path = os.getcwd()

#Retrieving the images and their labels
for i in range(classes):
    path = os.path.join(cur_path,'train',str(i))
    images = os.listdir(path)

    for a in images:
        try:
            image = Image.open(path + '\\'+ a)
            image = image.resize((30,30))
            image = np.array(image)
            #sim = Image.fromarray(image)
            data.append(image)
            labels.append(i)
        except:
            print("Error loading image")

#Converting lists into numpy arrays
data = np.array(data)
labels = np.array(labels)

print(data.shape, labels.shape)
#Splitting training and testing dataset
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)

#Converting the labels into one hot encoding
y_train = to_categorical(y_train, 43)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, 43)

#Building the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu', input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Dense(43, activation='softmax'))

#Compilation of the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs = 15
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
model.save("my_model.h5")
```

Comment: I think you need to give more details here. Please give `X_train.shape` value so that I can track it better.